# What value of capacitor should I use with this MP2307 buck regulator?

Tags: buck, capacitance, synchronous

I am designing a buck regulator using the MP2307 synchronous step-down converter chip, but I've encountered a problem.

The [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MP2307_r1.9.pdf) offers this example schematic, for a 3.3V output:

[image: example schematic]

I understand that to achieve a 5V output, I should change the values of R1 and R2. No problem there.

My confusion concerns the R/C network C3+R3. The "explanation" on pages 8-9 make absolutely no sense to me. Assume for the moment that I *don't* have a five-year degree in electrical engineering or advanced mathematics. I understand things like volts, amps, capacitance, ohm's law and so on; but the datasheet talks about concepts that mean nothing to me at all.

> The system has two poles of importance...

Huh?

> These poles are located at...

Huh?

> The system has one zero of importance...

Huh?

> The system may have another zero of importance...

Huh???

*This is not English!!* This is some made-up language that only has meaning to grey-haired engineering professors.

Maybe I'm just stupid.

Can someone please tell me what value of capacitor I should be using? I don't have any 3.9nF capacitors. Does it really matter? Can I use a 10nF instead? I have plenty of those.

For the record, I plan to use the circuit to power a Raspberry Pi from a higher voltage - say, somewhere between 6V and 12V.

Comment: On page 9 it specifically states how to calculate the compensation components. With the incorrect value there is a risk of instability or undesirable transient response.

Comment: In addition, I don't think I have any equipment capable of measuring the ESR of a capacitor.

Comment: Yes, it does. But as I don't understand the terminology, the formulae are meaningless to me. What is FZ1? What is a zero of importance? What is a pole? etc. I was hoping someone who was already familiar with all these confusing terms could just say "10nF would be fine" or what-have-you.

Comment: The terminology is from control system theory.  Power regulators have feedback so that the output voltage can remain constant over varying loads and other factors.  The compensation pin here is used to modify the feedback so that the power supply will remain stable.  For practical advice, I would say that if your input and load capacitances are similar to the example circuit, then you will probably be OK with the compensation components shown in that example.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but MPS does have a DCDC design tool that will tell you what capacitor you need.